# Problems with USB 2.0 extensions totalling 40+ft

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors

I have a tv about 40+ feet from my pc (multiple rooms and 1 level separate us) I want to use as another monitor. I ran HDMI to the tv which worked fine, but then I tried to run a chain of  multiple 10 ft USB 2.0 M/F from my computer to a USB 2.0 Hub, where I then plugged my keyboard and mouse into the hub. I did this without consulting anyone, and now realize I should have, as I am having problems getting my PC to recognize the devices plugged into the hub. I can plug a single device into the end of the USB chain and that works fine, however I do need two devices on the hub on the end.
Signal strength degradation isn't a big deal for me by the way as all I need it for is keyboard/mouse.

I've been reading about active extension USB and powered USB hubs today and think they might be able to solve my problem, but I am not familiar with them. Can anyone offer an idea for a setup so I can use a mouse and keyboard with this tv, all while my PC is 40+ feet away?

There were a couple similar questions I read that did not solve my problem by the way, so I don't think this is a duplicate. Sorry in advance for anything, as I'm new.

**please provide a solution for my desired setup**

Comment: The max length of a USB cable is 16 feet 5 inches - really the max distance a USB signal can travel is 16'5"

Comment: @Keltari I read that one, but USB extensions can still work on long lengths with active extension and or powered hubs, apparently. Also I needed advice on my specific setup in addition to this problem, so I did not think it would be considered duplicate. That article does not answer my question as it does not address active extensions and powered hubs.

Comment: You can increase the length with hubs, but just a small amount.  the signal timing gets degraded with hubs and extensions.  You might be able to extend it a little, but to much and it just wont work.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to break the USB length limitations

You can use multiple USB hubs (no more than 5m between them) or Active Cables.

> With the USB specs limiting the length of cables, is there a way to
>   extend those limits? Yes! However, in order to go beyond these cable
>   length limits (or recommended lengths) you need to use self-powered
>   USB hubs or active (repeater) cables; both of which have their own
>   limits as well. Other options such as USB over Ethernet or building
>   your own USB bridge can extend the USB range further. Back to Top
>
> **USB Hubs**:
>
> You can use extension cables and self-powered USB hubs connected
>   together to extend the range of your USB device. However, it is
>   important to remember when using 2.0 hubs and cables that the distance
>   between each powered hub can be no more than 5 meters (16 feet and 5
>   inches). When using 3.0/3.1 hubs and cables, do not exceed the
>   recommended length of 3 meters (9 feet and 10 inches) between hubs.
>   Note: It is possible to use bus-powered USB hubs, but you will quickly
>   run out of power as you extend your setup.
>
> **Active (Repeater) Extension Cables**:
>
> USB active extension cables contain electronics that regenerate the
>   USB signal. Active cables are essentially 1 port USB hubs. You can use
>   a regular USB cable in conjunction with an active cable as long as the
>   regular cable is not more than 5 meters (16 feet and 5 inches) long
>   for 2.0 devices and not more than 3 meters (9 feet and 10 inches) long
>   for 3.0 devices. Note: Typically, active cables are bus-powered
>   cables. To ensure you receive the full 500mA power of a USB port,
>   consider purchasing an active cable that includes a separate power
>   adapter.
>
> **USB Hub Limits and Maximum Length of Active Cables**
>
> Just like there is a limit on a regular (passive) USB cable, there is
>   also a limit on how long an active cable can be and how many USB hubs
>   you can use.
>
> **Maximum number of USB Hubs**:
>
> The USB 2.0/3.0/3.1 specifications call for only 7 tiers of devices to
>   be connected. When you count the devices on each end (the host and the
>   peripheral device), that only leaves 5 tiers available and a USB hub
>   is considered 1 tier. Thus, only a maximum of 5 USB hubs can be used
>   for a total maximum length of 30 meters (about 98 feet and 5 inches).
>
> **Maximum length of USB active (repeater) cable**:
>
> This number depends if you are using a regular cable with an active
>   cable or not. If you are not using a regular cable, then the maximum
>   active cable length for USB 2.0 is 30 meters (98 feet and 5 inches)
>   and the maximum recommended length for USB 3.0/3.1 is 18 meters (about
>   59 feet). If you are using a regular cable (max length of 5 meters for
>   2.0 and max length of 3 meters for 3.0/3.1) with an active cable, then the maximum length for USB 2.0 is 25 meters (about 82 feet) and the
>   maximum recommended length for USB 3.0/3.1 is 15 meters (about 49
>   feet).
>
> **Is there any way to go beyond the limit of active cables or hubs?**
>
> There are other ways you can extend a USB signal beyond the 30 meter
>   limit. You can use USB over Ethernet to achieve distances up to 100
>   meters (about 328 feet). Additionally, you can build your own USB
>   bridge to transmit data over different communication channels such as
>   wireless methods.

Source [USB Cable Length Limitations And How To Break Them](http://www.yourcablestore.com/USB-Cable-Length-Limitations-And-How-To-Break-Them_ep_42-1.html)

Comment: Hmm, so would using an appropriate length of active extension with a usb hub(powered or not?) on the end work?

Comment: It would appear so ...